# Call Recorder issue in some devices , Call recorder not working on device 7.1.1 , not able to record other person voice

Tags: android, call, android-6.0-marshmallow, mediarecorder, call-recording

> I was developing a android app for recording calls using media
>   recorder ,it was working fine for some devices but not recording voice
>   of other person on devices which are on 7.1.1 and greater ,specially
>   on moto g devices .

This is my media recorder code

```
recorder.setMaxDuration(60 * 60 * 1000);
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64 * 1024);
                    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44 * 1000 + 100);
                    recorder.setAudioChannels(MONO_CHANNEL);
```

Is there any way to achieve this .please suggest

Comment: Could you solve the issue?

Comment: Naah , It strill not working for some devices .

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem when recording call. Solve by change `audioSource` to `VOICE_COMMUNICATION`

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
```

Comment: I tried the same but its not working .same I can not hear other person voice .